# Jsoup: How to get an image src as an absolute uri?

Tags: java, uri, jsoup

I did this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlDescrizione);
Elements lista = doc.select("img");
Element url = lista.get(0);

System.out.println(url);
System.out.println(url.attr("abs:src"));
```

First line prints: `<img src="IMAGEURL..." alt="" border="1" width="80" height="59" />`
Second line prints empty string

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are parsing already read HTML code so your `doc` doesn't have any idea about base uri which can be used to build absolute path. If that is the case then you should specify explicitly base uri before you use `url.attr("abs:src")` or `url.absUrl("src")`.
You can do it for example with

```
doc.setBaseUri("http://your.domain.com/your/page");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if the scr attribute works together with the `abs:` prefix. According to the [Jsoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls) you can try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlDescrizione);
Element image = doc.select("img").get(0);;
String urlStr = image.absUrl("src");
System.out.println(urlStr);
```

note, that the `abs:` prefix as well as the `Node.absUrl("key")` method only work if the base path was given correctly to the Jsoup parser. So it seems likely that you also neeed to adjust your

```
Jsoup.parse(xmlDescrizione);
```

to something like

```
Jsoup.parse(xmlDescrizione, "THE/BASE/PATH");
```

Comment: It still returns an empty string.

Comment: Note my added comment about the base path

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to use image.absUrl("abs:href") rather than using src .it depends on the attribute key name